# Remove duplicate Items in multiple arraylist swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var brachNames = ["AP","AP","AP","AS","AS","AS","BR","BR","BR"]
var overAllTaget = ["84","84","84","84","84","84","84","84","84"]
var overAllSold = ["135","135","135","135","135","135","135","135","135"]
```

---

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable {
    func removeDups() -> [Element] {
        var uniquedElements = Set<Element>()
        return filter { uniquedElements.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

I want this type of output - [AP,84,135,AS,84,135,BR,84,135]

Comment: Set don't have orders. Also, why do you have 3 arrays, when it seems to be linked data (AP goes with 84 and 135)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've 3 different `Arrays`, you need to first combine these to get an `Array` of `Arrays` using `zip(_:_:)` and `map(_:)`, i.e.

```
var arr = zip(brachNames, zip(overAllTaget, overAllSold)).map { [$0.0, $0.1.0, $0.1.1] }
```

Now, use `Set` to filter out the duplicates. Then use `flatMap(_:)` to get a single `result` `Array`, i.e.

```
let result = Array(Set(arr)).flatMap{ $0 } //["AP", "84", "135", "AS", "84", "135", "BR", "84", "135"]
```

**Note:** `Set` is *unordered*. So, the sequence of the `result` might change.

Comment: Great. Do accept (tick on left) if it helped. Happy coding 

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a struct with the required fields (brachName, overallTarget, overallSold), comply to `Hashable` and apply something like this:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array

This way you could keep the order, if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to work with an array of a custom type instead of 3 different arrays of data to make the code clearer and to avoid simple mistakes when accessing the data. Below is an example of such solution using a `struct` to hold the data

```
struct BranchData: Hashable {
    let branchName: String
    let overallTarget: Int
    let overallSold: Int
}

var set = Set<BranchData>()

for (index, branch) in brachNames.enumerated() {
    guard index < overAllSold.count, index < overAllTaget.count else {
        break
    }
    set.insert(BranchData(branchName: branch, overallTarget: Int(overAllTaget[index]) ?? 0, overallSold: Int(overAllSold[index]) ?? 0))
}
```

To support the specific output with all values in an array we can add a computed property

```
extension BranchData {
    var propertyArray: [String] {
        [branchName, String(overallTarget), String(overallSold)]
    }
}

let output = set.flatMap { $0.propertyArray }
```

or a more direct approach

```
let output = set.flatMap { [$0.branchName, $0.overallTarget, $0.overallSold] }
```